# Compiled Code results in Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-word, interface

I have a .dotm file that contains multiple classes and modules.
There are 4 classes that implement an interface.
ChecklistTable is the interface (defines 1 Property and 3 Functions)
OverviewChecklistTable is one of the 4 classes implementing it.

### using the uncompiled version

Everything works as expected. No errors or unwated states/behaviours.

### using the compiled version

I get the type mismatch error 13 in the following function (inside my `ChecklistTableParser` class) Most of the times the error occurs while in this line `Set output = New OverviewChecklistTable`.

```
Private Function CreateCorrespondingTable(curTableType As TableType) As ChecklistTable
        
    Dim output As ChecklistTable
    Select Case curTableType
        Case ttmisc
            Set output = New MiscChecklistTable
        Case ttChecklistItem
            Set output = New ResultChecklistTable
        Case ttProjectData
            Set output = New ProjectDataChecklistTable
        Case ttOverView
            Set output = New OverviewChecklistTable
    End Select
    
    Set CreateCorrespondingTable = output
    
End Function
```

At this time it already created 5 `ChecklistTable`s. 1 `ProjectDataCechklistTable` and 4 `MiscChecklistTable`s.
Sometimes it creates only the `ProjectDataChecklistTable` without errors and then every other CechklistTable type throws the exception.

### Further Observations

Saving the compiled code creates a .dotm that is roughly 20 KB bigger than its not compiled version.

The .dotm increases in size (by roughly 1 KB) (without any actual change) when I:

1. Add some code or a comment
2. Compile the project
3. Save the project
4. Delete the code/comment
5. Compile the project
6. Save the project

### Question

What am I doing wrong? Shall I better not use Interfaces in VBA code?

### Edit

Initialization of OverViewChecklistTable

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pBase = New ChecklistTableBase
    Set pCellDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
```

ChecklistTableBase has no Class_Initialize() sub

### Edit 2

I had a circular dependency. After removing it, it seems that everything is working fine.

The ChecklistTables were stored in a container. But they also had a reference to this container, so that they could interact with other tables.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled code" in the context of VBA?

Comment: Is there any code in the class contructor(s) that could cause the issue?

Comment: When was the last time that you cleaned your code, i.e. exported and deleted all code modules, saved the project then re-imported them all? VBA is notorious for building up hidden crap that can cause random errors.

Comment: @GSerg In the IDE "Debug" > "Compile ..."

Comment: That would happen when you run the code anyway if it hasn't been done separately, so there is no difference.

Comment: @FunThomas No. They all instantiate ChecklistTableBase. The error also doesn't occur while instancing. I'll update my Question with the Class_Initialize() sub.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Like 2 weeks ago. The size of the project drastically decreased.

Comment: @GSerg You are right. The difference is, that I don't save the compiled .dotm. I only save the modified document.

Comment: First start by explicity declaring any parameters as ByVal or ByRef to avoid any unintended side effects.  Think you need to step through through the code.  Cant see where in the provided code the Type Mismatch could occur.  Assuming all implement an ChecklistTable.  Usually interfaces are named with a preceeding "I" to easily indentify.  Only hint maybe what's pBase declaratiion? as ChecklistTable/IChecklistTable?

Comment: pBase is of type ChecklistTableBase which doesn't implement an interface. This is the base class workaround for each class that implements ChecklistTable.

Answer (score 0):

### This is wrong. Will update.

The solution to my question is: Precede interface names with an 'I'
`ChecklistTable` => `IChecklistTable`

Thanks to M. Johnstone. I would have never guessed, that this was the problem.

(IMO naming conventions shouldn't break code)

Comment: You don't have to have an I preceding interface names - if you look at the documentation for Implements they don't use I. It is just a convention to make it easier to identify which things belong to what - as M. Johnstone explicitly stated. If that was the only change you make then the problem was probably ambuiguity .

Comment: Yeah you are right and my answer is wrong. I used the Replace all projectwide functionality ChecklistTable ==> ChecklistTableFoo also worked. I am still figuring out what breaks the interface and then I'll update my answer.